# ajax call pass the valu but controller get one property value and another get null value in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

here is my ajax code

```
 var viewmodel = {
            "pin": $(".password").val(),
            "STRetailerVMList": STRetailerVMList
 var url = '@Url.Action("StockTransferToRetailer", "Create")';

 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(viewmodel),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                return confirm("Please confrim to transfer?");
            },
        });
```

and here is my controller code.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(StockTransferToRetailerVMList viewmodel)
        {
            return Json(new { });
        }
```

model call

```
    public class StockTransferToRetailerVMList
    {
        public string  Pin { get; set; }
        public List<StockTransferRetailerViewModel> STRetailerVMList { get; set; }
    }
```

when i inspect the browser as developer mood then we can see request payload
[network section request payload data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvfAn.png)
but when we receive into the controller we get only one value property and another show null, but when pass multiple list it receive properly
[controller code image when receive data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPfg.png)

thanks in advance

i want to expect that ajax call value properly can receive in the conroller

Comment: You miss a `}` in your `var viewmodel = {}`.

Comment: @QingGuo It is a my mistaek when i  posted, but i am still facing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make some change as below:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
         data: viewmodel,
        //data: JSON.stringify(viewmodel),
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            return confirm("Please confrim to transfer?");
        },
    });
```

result:
[image]

**Update :**

This is how I create  `STRetailerVMList` :

```
var STRetailerVMList = new Array();
var List = { IsChecked: true };
STRetailerVMList.push(List);
```

**Update2:**
This is my test code, you can try it:

```
<button id="btn_New"> submit</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#btn_New').on('click', function () {

        var STRetailerVMList = new Array();       
        var List = { "IsChecked": true };
        STRetailerVMList.push(List);

        var viewmodel = {
            "Pin": "111",
            "STRetailerVMList": STRetailerVMList
        };
        console.log(viewmodel);
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create","StockTransferToRetailer")';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: viewmodel,               
                beforeSend: function () {
                    return confirm("Please confrim to transfer?");
                },
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: STRetailerVMList still get null

Comment: @Mithun Chandra Howlader Please see my update. Try it, If not work , could you share how you create the STRetailerVMList?

Comment: `var STRetailerVMList = [];
   `

i create this way but use your `var STRetailerVMList = new Array();` code but still facing problem

Comment: `if (this.checked) {
                    const rowData = {
                        "Retailer": $(this).closest('tr').find('#retailer').val(),
                    };
                    STRetailerVMList.push(rowData);
                }`

Comment: @ 
Qing Guo
  u can see my network section request payload data image

Comment: @MithunChandraHowlader  my console like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToIXL.png

Comment: @ 
Qing Guo

yes i get the data in the console but get not in the controller https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvfAn.png

Comment: @Mithun Chandra Howlader , Have a try my test code, and see the console not network.

Comment: @MithunChandraHowlader  Is your problem solved ? If not , could you  build a small demo and share it via gihub ? so that we can help you.